# Python script running in a Raspberry Pi without initialization

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have written a python script which waits for a keyboard input and it will run in a Raspberry Pi.
I want it to run as soon as the Raspi gets powered (without the need to log in and to type the command in order to start the script). Note that it is not a deamon, since it will interact with the user. How can I do that?

Comment: It is meant to run as a GUI program or in terminal?

Comment: How is it going to interact with "the user" if nobody's logged in? There is no user at that point.

Comment: You might want to split it into two parts—a daemon that starts at startup, communicating with a user program that starts at login. (This kind of thing is more common in the Apple world, where you can have system or user "LaunchDaemons" that communicate with user "LaunchAgents" and `launchd` does all the hard work for you, but the same basic idea works on any *nix platform.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the instructions on this page:
http://www.akeric.com/blog/?p=1976
very helpful to achieve what you are asking. Specifically the page describes how to configure the pi to automatically log in to one of the shells and how you can then run a script as the shell starts up. 
Note that when I used this approach, the pi was not exposed to the outside world, so I did not check this approach for possible security weaknesses.

belated edit since the original answer was 'link only':

including the relevant content from the link to summarize the necessary steps here in case the link falls dead:

edit inittab (e.g. using nano):

```
sudo nano /etc/inittab
```

replace this line:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
```

with this:

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

This will automatically login on `tty1` upon startup. Then you can start your script e.g. by including it into the `.bashrc`.